# I moved my WordPress site to the main directory and now I can't access my admin

Tags: installation, migration

I have a site here: http://www.m2comm-semi.com/new that decided to move here: http://www.m2comm-semi.com/

I followed this tutorial:

http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/how-to-safely-move-wordpress/

1. I deactivated the permalinks
2. Changed this line:

   /** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
   require('./new/wp-blog-header.php');

Of the index file located in my root folder (initially I was using `wordpress`):

[image]

The main page works but when I want to access the admin: http://www.m2comm-semi.com/wp-admin I get a 404 Not Found.

**EDIT:**

I even did this trick in `function.php` of the `new` folder:

```
<?php

define('WP_HOME','http://www.m2comm-semi.com/new');  
define('WP_SITEURL','http://www.m2comm-semi.com/');
```

Didn't work either. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there, it's just the other way around:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://www.m2comm-semi.com/new');  
define('WP_SITEURL','http://www.m2comm-semi.com');
```

`WP_HOME`is the URL where the actual files are and `WP_SITEURL` is the URL under which you access the site. Also be aware that this doesn't go in the `functions.php` but in the `wp-config.php`

The Admin is always accessible via the actual location of the files, so in this case:

http://www.m2comm-semi.com/new/wp-admin

Some more info in the Codex:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory

Comment: So I can't access my admin at http://www.m2comm-semi.com/wp-admin with this technique?

Comment: No, but once this is set up properly as explained WordPress will be smart enough to redirect you if you access that address.

Comment: So what am I missing? To set it up in a proper way?

Comment: Oh I thought you're just asking and haven't tried yet.

Comment: Never mind. `http://www.m2comm-semi.com/wp-admin` started working...after a day. Weird.